# How to get the week slot of activity in Moodle?

Tags: php, moodle

I add an **activity** (say assignment) in particular week section `Moodle`.Consider now I have only access to that activity. How i know the start and end date of that activity?

Consider I add activity under

```
30 September - 6 October.
```

How can I get this date??

I know the logged in user details are available in **$USER** object and this is accessable from any page.

similarly i have to get the date slot of the activity from some pages. How can I get this. I think the question is clear and any help is great....

Answer (score 0):

This is part of the Availability API : https://docs.moodle.org/dev/Availability_API

It depends on the context where you want to pick up those informations.

For example, the Assign activity has the database fields `duedate` and `allowsubmissionsfromdate` that allow you to get the start and end date of the activity.

This could be a query like the one above :

```
global $DB;
$query = 'SELECT id, duedate, allowsubmissionsfromdate FROM {assign} WHERE id = :id';
$results = $DB->get_record_sql($query, array('id' => 1));
```

**EDIT :**

You should look into the `mdl_course_sections` table. The Week course format defines two dates `availablefrom` and `availableuntil`.

After getting your course ID (there are different ways to do this)

```
$context = context_course::instance($course->id);
```

You can make a query with the acitivity ID like :

```
$section = 'select section from {course_modules} WHERE id = :id';
$results = $DB->get_record_sql($section, array('id' => xxx));
```

And then query the `mdl_course_sections` table using the section ID just you got from the last query :

```
$dates = 'select availablefrom, availableuntil from {course_modules} WHERE id = :sectionid';
```

Check out those sample results providing the timestamp values giving you the ability to get the week of the section :

```
mysql> select id, availablefrom, availableuntil
       from mdl_course_modules
       where availablefrom <> 0
       and availableuntil <> 0; 
+-----+---------------+----------------+
| id  | availablefrom | availableuntil |
+-----+---------------+----------------+
| 590 |    1414713600 |     1417392000 |
| 591 |    1414713600 |     1419984000 |
+-----+---------------+----------------+
```

Comment: thanks, but i not want the duedate or allowsubmissionsfromdate etc, i want the week in which that activity belongs to.